# "Mit diese Tipps" - ist das ein Schreibfehler?

Tags: spelling

"Mit diese Tipps" ("diese" statt "diesen") - ist das richtig? Ich habe das in einem Artikel in "Die Welt" gesehen. Auch Google zeigt 30'000 Ergebnisse mit dieser Wortkombination.

*UPD* Der ganze Satz lautet: "Mit diese Tipps lassen sich die Feiertage vernünftig begehen." (https://www.welt.de/wissenschaft/plus222969492/Corona-und-Weihnachten-Das-gemeinsame-Essen-ist-eine-der-heikelsten-Situationen.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bei solchen Fragen sind bitte **IMMER** ganze Sätze zu posten, niemals herausgegriffene Phrasen. Grammatik ist die Kunst, Wörter zu *Sätzen* zusammenzufügen, nicht zu *Wortgruppen.*

Prinzipiell ist aber trotzdem zu sagen, dass die Wortgruppe *»mit diese Tipps«* praktisch immer falsch ist. Aber ohne weitere Informationen kann man aber nicht mit Sicherheit sagen, was richtig wäre. In den meisten Fällen sollte es tatsächlich *»diesen«* statt *»diese«* heißen. Aber nicht immer.

Es könnte schlichtweg ein Satzzeichen zwischen *»mit«* und *»diese Tipps«* fehlen. Die folgenden Beispiele zeigen Sätze, in denen ganz korrekt ein Satzzeichen gesetzt wurde. Würde es fehlen, läge die gesuchte fehlerhafte Wortfolge vor, aber der Fehler läge nicht am fehlenden *n*:

> Wenn ein Mensch an einem Burnout erkrankt, leiden auch immer Familie und Freunde **mit - diese Tipps** helfen.
> <sup>[Quelle](https://www.ellviva.de/krankheiten/psyche/burnout-tipps)</sup>

> Coronavirus fährt **mit: Diese Tipps** solltest du beachten
> <sup>[Quelle](https://insider.mopo.de/inside-digital/corona-wie-gefaehrlich-sind-e-scooter-und-carsharing-dienste.html/amp)</sup>

> Auf alle Fälle werden wir - meine Frau macht da auch immer gerne **mit - diese Tipps** in die Tat umsetzen und dann hier natürlich in Wort und Bild berichten.
> <sup>[Quelle](https://www.namibia-forum.ch/forum/17-news/266193-wer-hat-tipps-fuer-3-tage-tsumkwe.html?start=6)</sup>

Es kann aber auch etwas anders falsch sein:

> mit → mir
> Mein Dank geht an @borkenkäfer, der/die **mit diese Tipps** gegeben hat!
> <sup>[Quelle](https://citv.nl/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2717)</sup>

---

Man sollte auch mit der Angabe von Treffern bei der Google-Suche vorsichtig sein:
Wenn ich bei Google nach »"mit diese Tipps"« suche (also in Anführungszeichen, um genau diese Wortfolge zu suchen), behauptet Google ungefähr 179.000 Ergebnisse zu finden:

[image: 179.000 Treffer bei Google]

Geht man bis zur Seite 8, sind es plötzlich nur mehr ungefähr 76 Ergebnisse:

[image: 76 Treffer]

Google lag also mit seiner ersten Einschätzung um satte 235.426,32% über dem tatsächlichen Wert.

Die falsche Wortfolge ist also in Wahrheit weitaus seltener als vorerst angenommen.

Comment: Danke. Ich habe meine Nachricht bearbeitet - jetzt ist der ganze Satz da.

Comment: In general, I find that Google's result counts aren't that reliable as an indicator of whether something is correct. As you point out, it doesn't allow for punctuation, and it includes text by people who aren't using proper German for various reasons. NGrams is somewhat better in this respect. See, for example, [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mit+diese+Tipps%2Cmit+diesen+Tipps&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmit%20diesen%20Tipps%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmit%20diesen%20Tipps%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 4):

Tatsächlich ist das ein Fehler. Nach *mit* folgt der Dativ, daher muss es *mit diesen Tipps* heißen.

Comment: Bitte beantworte Fragen, die auf deutsch gestellt wurden, in deutscher Sprache. Du weißt nicht, ob der Fragesteller überhaupt Englisch spricht. Davon abgesehen ist dies hier ein Deutsch-Forum. Im Zweifelsfall ist also immer Deutsch zu verwenden. Hier liegt aber ohnehin kein Zweifelsfall vor.

Comment: Absolut korrekt, ich habe gar nicht wahrgenommen, dass die Frage auf Deutsch war, danke für den Hinweis!